# ios decide whether to silent my remote notification under some conditions on client side code instead of setting content-available

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, notifications, remote-notifications

I am trying to implement silent remote condition on CLIENT SIDE.

Basically, I will receive a notification from the server and once I received, I will decide whether to silent the notification depends on some conditions before user device get notified.

So instead of setting content-available on server side, I wondering if there's any way to implement this on client side (iOS Swift code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, that cannot be done.

From your server, after you sent the notification to APNS, the next time any codes done by you can be run is when the user response to the notification or launch your app. Apple handles everything in-between.